# Angle/Energy Dependent CDF for Compton Scattering

Tags: particle-physics, computational-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I was trying to code some Monte Carlo calculations regarding x-ray matter interactions and came to the point where I wanted to sample the energy transfer or the scattering angle. However I had some difficulty with turning the Klein-Nishina differential cross-section into a cumulative distribution function. Namely I ended up finding negative CDF values at a photon energy of 10keV.

**How do I best find a normalized CDF for Compton scattering that only depends on pre- and post-scatter energy?**

What I tried to do is

1. start with the Klein-Nishina differential cross-section $\frac{d\sigma}{d\cos(\theta)d\phi} = A \left(\frac{E'}{E}\right)^2\left[\frac{E'}{E} + \frac{E}{E'} - \sin^2(\theta)\right]$
2. substitute the $\theta$ terms with the corresponding energy post scatter $E'$ using $E' = \frac{E}{1+(1-\cos(\theta))E/mc^2}$
3. "integrate" both sides with respect to $\phi$
4. calculate the indefinite integral with respect to $E'$

What I got in the end was (for simplicity expressed with $\epsilon = E'/E$, $k=\frac{mc^2}{E}$ and $l=\frac{1}{1-2/k}$ and up to a constant factor)
$$F(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon^3}{3} - k\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)\cdot \epsilon^2 + k\cdot ln\left(\frac{l}{\epsilon}\right) + \left(1-2k-2k^2\right) \cdot \epsilon$$

With the normalized CDF I was looking for being $G(\epsilon)=\frac{F(\epsilon)-F(l)}{F(1)-F(l)}$. $l$ was the same as $\epsilon$ at $\theta = \pi$, so I used it as a lower integration bound.

When I threw that into python to plot it for $E=10keV$ over $E' \in [l\cdot E,E]$ I got this:
[image: wrong Compton CDF I found]

It looks mostly sensible, but in the beginning it goes below 0 which doesn't really make sense...

I tried looking around for other people solving this problem and found [this old paper](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/7075175). And while the function I'm looking for must be in there somewhere, all of the expressions are so obfuscated and the typeface so hard to read that I didn't really manage to extract it. Maybe some of the substitution names are standard and someone else has an easier time with it ^^

**Is that procedure not sound? Did I just a wrong lower integration bound? Or is there just another arithmetic error hidden in my notebook?**

I also tried to substitute $E'$ for $\theta$, but I (or better said wolfram alpha) couldn't solve the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well-known cross section formula for Compton scattering is
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
=\frac{\alpha^2(\hbar c)^2}{2s}
\left(\frac{\omega'}{\omega}\right)^2
\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega'}+\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\sin^2\theta\right)
$$
where
$$
\omega'=\frac{\omega}{1+\frac{\hbar\omega}{mc^2}(1-\cos\theta)}
$$

We can integrate $d\sigma$ to obtain a cumulative distribution function.
Let $I(\theta)$ be the following integral of $d\sigma$.
(The $\sin\theta$ is due to $d\Omega=\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$)
\begin{equation*}
I(\theta)=
\int
\left(\frac{\omega'}{\omega}\right)^2
\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega'}+\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\sin^2\theta\right)
\sin\theta\,d\theta
\end{equation*}

The solution is
\begin{multline*}
I(\theta)=-\frac{\cos\theta}{R^2}
+\log\big(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\big)\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{2}{R^3}\right)
\\
{}-\frac{1}{2R\big(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\big)^2}
+\frac{1}{1+R(1-\cos\theta)}\left(-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{1}{R^3}\right)
\end{multline*}
where
\begin{equation*}
R=\frac{\hbar\omega}{mc^2}
\end{equation*}

The cumulative distribution function is
$$
F(\theta)=\frac{I(\theta)-I(0)}{I(\pi)-I(0)},\quad 0\le\theta\le\pi
$$

To plot $F(E'/E)$, convert $E'/E$ to $\theta$ using Compton's formula.
$$
\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{mc^2}{E}-\frac{mc^2}{E'}+1\right)
$$